# Glitch in review for Late Answers?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Not sure what happened here but my Late Answers queue just blew up.

[image]

All the answers it is asking me to review are from random dates, some very old some new, and don't appear to actually have been answered/modified recently. Is there a reason for this?

EDIT: All the answers are from low rep users though. It looks like it's only taking the 'new user' part into account and not when they answered. Just all answers from all new users ever.

Comment: I saw the exact same thing, perhaps some new code was applied. Anyway, I saw that most were chipping in to decrease that number (up to the limit of 20/3h).

Comment: @Xabre I chipped in a lot just trying to figure out wtf was happening haha

Comment: Think we all felt the same way :p Nice work @DasBeasto!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a known thing: [Raise the rep bar on late answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267080/1438)

The short answer is we recently expanded the pool of people eligible for having their late answers added to that queue. It was very effective in terms of adding more review tasks because it wasn't time limited. All eligible answers going back to the start of the site got added a few days ago, but the sudden spike will dissipate as people complete the reviews.

Once things settle down, the effect of the change should be only a few extra answers on the queue every now and then. It should *not* be a continual flood of tasks like you see here.

Sorry about the alarm.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that something was changed in the algorithm to determine what constitutes a late answer.  Especially since many of the "late" answers were given years ago.

I've cleared the queue in the mean time, but it didn't seem like anything to worry about.